Ignore Accent Differences in Zsh Autocomplete
Suppose I have a directory named cálculo in the current directory. How can I autocomplete its name after typing the starting characters without the accent?
$ cd calc<tab>
$ cd cálculo/

I failed to find anything about this in the documentation. One solution I thought about was using a matcher-list for every possible case. In this example, a simple m:a=á. It does work, however only if I try to autocomplete after typing ca only. Not after calc. Not sure what I'm missing.

I think matcher-list (i.e. compadd -M matching control) just doesn't work with multibyte characters. It didn't in 2018 and this doesn't seem to have improved in the past few years.
